# Youtube API download captions (using PHP example)

Tags: php, youtube

I'm working from [Youtube Data API - Captions: download](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download), Using the PHP example
I can get the list of transcripts successfully, 
but **cannot download the transcript**. 
After entering caption track ID and hitting GO, it breaks the page.

If I try a track ID from a video without CC contributions allowed, I get the **correct** error of:

> A service error occurred: The permissions associated with the request
>   are not sufficient to download the caption track. The request might
>   not be properly authorized, or the video order might not have enabled
>   third-party contributions for this caption.

I've tried excluding the second optional parameter on $youtube->captions->download, with no luck.
It breaks when it tries to print $captionResource (I'm new to debugging PHP)

```
//(original from Youtube API examples)  
function downloadCaption(Google_Service_YouTube $youtube, $captionId, &$htmlBody) {
    // Call the YouTube Data API's captions.download method to download an existing caption.
    $captionResouce = $youtube->captions->download($captionId, array(
        'tfmt' => "srt",
        'alt' => "media"
    ));

    $htmlBody .= "<h2>Downloaded caption track</h2><ul>";
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s</li>',
      $captionResouce);
    $htmlBody .= '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it working in the python example, but would prefer PHP

Comment: How do you login with OAuth2? Is there a way to login without any user interation? I'd like to automate downloading captions

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$captionResource` try `$captionResource->getBody()->getContents()`.